# Json Data Reading in Pig Latin

Tags: apache-pig

I want to read the nested data in Json in PigLatin

```
{"info":{"Id":53556,"State":"Ohio"},"time":139140}  
{"info":{"Id":3554,"State":"Calif"},"time":1391407471477}
```

I am doing it using

```
read = load '$json_file' USING JsonLoader('Id : chararray, state : chararray, time : chararray');
```

and storing read data into `/tmp/data.csv using PigStorage (',', '-noschema');`

But I am getting junk values in data.csv . Any idea if I am reading it incorrectly or storing it incorrectly ?

Comment: Can someone comment on this ? Is there problem in my usage of JsonLoader ?

Answer (score 0):

The schema in your LOAD statement is incorrect. ***info*** is a *name* and *{"Id":53556,"State":"Ohio"}* is its ***value***. This value is an ***object*** which is again an unordered set of name/value pairs i.e. *"Id":53556* and *"State":"Ohio"*

Try this

```
read = 
        LOAD 'test.dat' 
        USING JsonLoader('
                info:(
                        id       : CHARARRAY
                        , state  : CHARARRAY )
                , time : CHARARRAY
        ');

proj = 
        FOREACH read 
        GENERATE 
            FLATTEN(info) AS (
                    id
                    , state )
            , time
        ;

proj2 = 
        FOREACH proj 
        GENERATE 
                state
                , time
        ;

dump proj2;
```

Output

```
(Ohio,139140)
(Calif,1391407471477)
```